# Multiple databases with ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating an RoR application with multiple databases.
As example i've got two databases called:

- Dashboard (which holds all user entries, group table, bearer table, companie table)
- Store (which holds all products, catalogs ...)

I manage to store this models in separate DBs by creating two database.yml files and call the method establish_connection in the Model.
Unfortunately ActiveStorage doesn't rely on the Models DB.

I saw that ActiveStorage has its own models "Blob & Attachment" which are extending ActiveRecord::Base.
To store the entries ActiveStorage runs the method has_one_attached() which is in the model.rb file:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/lib/active_storage/attached/model.rb

How can I manipulate this method in the ActiveStorage Engine, to call instead of ActiveStorages Blob, my own StoreBlob Model which then contains "establish_connection STORE_DB"?

Answer (score 0):

Create the models  ActiveStorage::Blob and ActiveStorage::Attachment in your app with your connection, in my case was postgres.

```
class ActiveStorage::Attachment < PostgresModelBase
```

I have my connection define in other class PostgresModelBase

After that you need to copy all the content in the model from activestorage gem into your new models.

Hope works!!

Comment: if someone find a 'better way' and more 'elegant' to do it please  post the solution here

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is i would store the blob metadata in a `jsonb` column called `blob_json` in database B in `MyModelB`

Then in Database A, in my model i would use:

```rb
class MyModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one_attached :file, service: application_b_amazon # in storage.yml create this service so that it points to the bucket in Application B just in case it's different
end

class MyModelB <  ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :database_b
end
```

Finally I would do

```rb
my_model_a = MyModelA.create(title: '...')

my_model_b = MyModelB.find(1) # This would retrieve

# This would create a blob WITHOUT UPLOADING with the same key retrieved from the json. ==> It's a link/pointer
new_blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.create_before_direct_upload(JSON.parse(my_model_b.blob_json)

# Finally you attach the blob
my_model_a.attach(new_blob)
```

You can also duplicate the file on your own bucket. but depends on your needs, if you're importing, that could make things slow.

The core idea is, on Service/Database B, you serialize the blob in column. then you retrieve that, and create your own AS blob with the same key pointing to the file on the Service B bucket.

if you want to disable purges, you can override the purge method on this model ( would need to read the activestorage source code to make sure you disable all possible methods if needed)
For our own case we didn't because it didn't matter.